# Count string using jQuery with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My textarea can count string/character when user enter input. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/nrkXG/1/).

My problem is I want set condition mean when string/character is 158 above, I want show message inside `<div id="message">We will deduct 2 credit from your account</div>` and same when string/character is 316 above the message will update and show<`div id="message">We will deduct 3 credit from your account</div>` and continue ..

Example:

```
158 *2

158 = We will deduct 2 credit from your account
316 = We will deduct 3 credit from your account
474 = We will deduct 4 credit from your account
632 = We will deduct 5 credit from your account
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    $('#charCount').text(this.value.length);

    var c = parseInt(this.value.length / 158);
    if(c > 0) 
        $('#message').text('We will deduct '+c+' credit from your account');
});​
```

Comment: but why when i delete string/character the message not update ?

Answer (score 0):

1) find length of String

2) Divide it by 158

3) Add '1' to the answer

4) Create message using String concatenation - "We will deduct" + output of (3) + "credit from your account"

5) jQuery("#message").html("We will deduct" + output of (3) + "credit from your account");

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    var len = this.value.length ; 
    $('#charCount').text(len);
    var creditCount = 158;
    if( len > creditCount ){
         var credits = Math.floor(len / creditCount );
         $('#message').html('We will deduct '+  credits  + ' credit from your account;' )
    }
});​
```

**[Check DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nrkXG/8/)**

Comment: There's a typo in your demo at Line 4. Maybe the code you expect is "var creditCount = 158;"?

Comment: Its not a typo actually.. Was testing my code with just a smaller input :)  .. Fixed that

Answer (score 0):

on textarea keyup you can check no. of characters presents and accordingly you can write if-else conditions to display the message.

check this:[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrkXG/7/)

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    if(this.value.length<=158)
    $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 1 credit from your account');
    else if(this.value.length>158 || this.value.length<316)
    $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 2 credit from your account');
    else if(this.value.length>316|| this.value.length<316)
    $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 3 credit from your account');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    $('#charCount').text(this.value.length);
    var length = this.value.length;
    if (length % 158 == 0) {
      $('#message').html('We will deduct '+ (length/158) + 
                         ' credit from your account;' )                        
    }
});
```